# Storing sqrt in BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, sqrt

I'm calculating the euclidean distance of two numbers and I have this equation :

```
 import java.lang.*;
 import static java.lang.Math.pow;
 import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {            
            double x2 = 0.32061253;
            double x1 = 0.25090585;
            double y2 = 0.33407547;
            double y1 = 0.30716705;

            double distance = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1,2) + pow(y2 - y1,2));
            System.out.println(distance);
 }
```

When I try to save this in a double variable (euclideanDistance), I get 0.0 when I print it (probably because the numbers have many decimals). I tried saving it using the BigDecimal format but it doesn't seem to work. How do I use it correctly in this case, since `sqrt` returns a double?

Comment: Post your code, your inputs, your expected output, your actual output.

Comment: The expected output is 0.30104542160445247, the actual output is 0.0. The code is pretty identical to what I posted, x2 x1 y2 y1 are all doubles (they all have 10 decimals: 1.4666362219)

Comment: The post is not valid Java code, and having an output without inputs doesn't help. Is that really complicated to post your code, your inputs and your outputs?

Comment: We'd like to see an entire example that we can compile and run - shouldn't be big, just enough so we can see how you're declaring the variables and how you're trying to print.

Comment: @JBNizet well, I guess we have the reputation of being wizards here at stackoverflow.  We should be able to just divine what's on everyone's mind.

Comment: Updated the first post with the code, @Mikenakis : Thanks for the reply - keep the sarcasm to yourself though.

Comment: And your code is still not valid Java code. Sigh...

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as you have not provided a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Alright, @MikeNakis and user1823812.  Both of you need to calm down and [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).  Mike, I share your frustration about the OP not asking a good question, but you must understand it was asked in good faith, and sarcastic comments like that do not help new users learn how to use the site properly.  OP, please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Math.pow() takes two doubles, you are only passing one double with pow(x2 - x1).

Comment: updated , forgot to add the , 2. Sorry but the mobile version isn't really good.

Comment: tell me user1823812, is the code above the only code you have ?(apart from the missing `Main` class :) ) ? because as Neil F says we don't see the result you're seeing

Comment: you are also missing a closing brace.

Comment: I think this should be closed as "a simple typographical error. "

Comment: @bhspencer exactly what closing brace ? do you mean the class `Main` ?

Comment: if by a chance your problem isn't solved with `double`, you can use Apfloat (http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/), I still advise you to refactor your code until it does print `0.0` and then post it :)

Answer (score 1):

This code prints out *an* answer, but not the one supplied in the comments, and it does not print '0.0' either - JDK 1.8

```
import java.lang.*;

import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x2 = 0.32061253;
        double x1 = 0.25090585;
        double y2 = 0.33407547;
        double y1 = 0.30716705;

        double distance = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
        System.out.println(distance);
    }
}

//result
//0.0747200395042642
```

Also tested with a Pythagorean triple 3,4,5:

- (x2-x1) = 3,
- (y2-y1) = 4
- output: 5

Comment: Looking at wikipedia for the formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance, this is the correct java implementation of the formula.